# How to get value of checked checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```js
alert($(".reg_title").attr(':checked'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mr." name="reg_title" class="reg_title" checked="" id="male">
    Mr
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mrs." name="reg_title" class="reg_title" id="female">
    Mrs
</label>
```

It alerting undefined. Why this error is happening please help me. How can I resolve this Error?

Answer (score 1):

use `:checked` as selector and `.attr('value')` like `alert($(".reg_title:checked").attr('value'));`

```js
alert($(".reg_title:checked").attr('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mr." name="reg_title" class="reg_title" checked="" id="male">
    Mr
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Mrs." name="reg_title" class="reg_title" id="female">
    Mrs
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.reg_title:checked').val();
```

Should get you there